# Scope of __device__ qualifier

Tags: cuda

On http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#device-variable-qualifier it says that a __device_ qualifier variable has the "lifetime of an application". Does this mean the kernel? If there are several kernels, how can CUDA know which variable belongs to which kernel?

If i declare a __device_ variable like so:

```
void someHOSTfunction() {
   __device__ int var;
   // Launch kernel etc...
}
```

Is "var" still global in the sense that it is still accessible from a kernel launched from a different function, even though it is "local" on the stack of someHOSTfunction() and gets scoped (?) when someHOSTfunction() returns? Does it make any difference to write it like this:

```
__device__ int var;
void someHOSTfunction() {
   // Launch kernel etc...
}
```

Now var is a global variable. But that means it is also accessible from other translation units. This probably won't work to prevent that:

```
static __device__ int var;
void someHOSTfunction() {
   // Launch kernel etc...
}
```

What would be the appropriate way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
void someHOSTfunction() {
   __device__ int var;
   // Launch kernel etc...
}
```

is illegal in CUDA. A `__device__` variable declaration is not allowed inside a function body,  and the compiler will emit an error if you try to do so. You must declare them at translation unit scope. The restriction applies to any function, be it `__host__` or  `__device__`.

If you need different statically declared `__device__` variables for different kernels, then use a different variable name for each. Or use a runtime allocated variable and pass it as an argument to your kernel, or use template parameter variables, or something else. But what you describe is impossible in CUDA as it exists today.

Comment: Is this true of the function is on the device: i.e. __ device__ void fun() {}? Afaik it is possible to declare a __ shared__ var in that way

Comment: If function is declared as `__device__` it will be accessible **only** form the device code (i.e. from within the kernel or any other `__device__` function). `__shared__` refers only to variables and means that they will be stored in thread shared memory (all threads from one block will have access to the variable). See the link for further info: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-language-extensions

Comment: I was a bit unspecific. I meant that if I declare a __device __ variable in a __device __ function, would that be ok?

Comment: @Bwawhwmopoloin: no that is illegal too. It doesn't matter what type of function body is involved.